# How do I give a delayed response in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework FormFlow to get a user to complete a form. Having completed it that Dialog ends and the method specified for the `ResumeWith` parameter (in this case `quoteComplete`) is executed:

```
var quoteForm = new FormDialog<Quote>(new Quote(), 
    quoteFormBuilder.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);

context.Call<Quote>(quoteForm, quoteComplete);
```

In `quoteComplete` I want the bot to tell the user that it is getting a quote and that it may takes a few seconds. An async call to perform the quote is then done and on it's return I want the bot to show another message with the value of the quote:

```
await context.PostAsync("I will now calculate your quote. I won't be long...");
context.Wait(MessageReceived);

//Simulate getting the quote
Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    context.PostAsync("Your quote is £133.54");
});
```

I also tried following advice in the documentation for sending multiple replies by putting this in the `Delay().ContinueWith`:

```
var message = context.MakeMessage();
message.Text = "Your quote is for £133.54";
var connector = new ConnectorClient();
connector.Messages.SendMessage(message);
```

However I get an `Access Denied` error for this.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I'm afraid not - still hoping someone with an answer will chip in! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instantiating the client in the following way

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
{
     var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();
     client.Messages.SendMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, but I wonder if you could update your answer with an explanation as to why this is necessary? Otherwise I'm just cut and pasting more SO magic! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ConnectorClient to send a response to the incoming message once your async task gets you a result

[Here's](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/replying/#navtitle) the link to the documentation

Comment: That's what I tried on my second attempt in my OP, but got Access Denied. Is there an easy way to construct the message - it's not obvious how I would use CreateReplyMessage when I am initiating the message.