# Send Message error 500 in Microsoft BotConnectorBot

Tags: facebook, bots, botframework

I'm working with Bot Connector to reply message. 
I using incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage() it worked, but i new ConnectorClient() to reply then 500 Internal Server Error. Non-bots can't talk to non-bots

```
public async Task＜Message＞ Post([FromBody]Message incomingMessage)
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient();

        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("ねぇ"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("お返事ちょうだい？"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("なんでお返事くれないの？"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("どうして？"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("私のこと捨てるの？"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("ねぇ"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("なんで？"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("嘘つき"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("なんでこんなひどいことするの？"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("なんで？"));
        connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？なんで？"));

        return incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("今あなたの家の前にいるの");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same problem, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334528/5951301 helped me to solve it:

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))   
{
    var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();
    client.Messages.SendMessage(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, and in my case it was because I was using the Bot Framework Emulator to invoke my bot logic (the Post method). The only way I got the direct connection via ConnectorClient working was to do a real end-to-end test via a configured channel (like Skype).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9000"), new ConnectorClientCredentials());
connector.Messages.SendMessage(message.CreateReplyMessage("Simple Text"));
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".